# Pandas fill method with respect to another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two columns in my dataset. One is **state** and other one is **city**. There are no `NaN` values in state column. But in city column too many `NaN` values are present.

Suppose I have one state data point value is "Washington" and in same row `NaN` value in **city**. I want to fill all `NaN` **city** values whose state is Washington with `Seattle`

How I can do this?

Comment: Can you add sample input and expected output to the question? Please create [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose the name of your dataset is df

The first thing you need to do is to locate the data  having **state** as **Washington** and fill it using the `fillna()` method and store it into some variable (let's say fill)

```
fill= df.loc[df['state']=='Washington'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

In the next step, you will again use the `fillna()` method in the original dataframe to fill all the values having **state** as **Washington**

```
df.fillna(value=fill)
```

Hope this answer helps :}

Answer (score 0):

assuming `df`

```
    STATE   CITY
0  StateA  CityA
1  StateB  CityB
2  StateA    NaN
3  StateB    NaN
```

filling of `df` with respect to default city of state

```
mapping = {"StateA": "city of state A","StateB": "city of state B"} #state default city mapping
df['CITY'] = df['STATE'].combine(df['CITY'], lambda state,city :  mapping[state] if pd.isnull(city) else city)
```

output:

```
    STATE             CITY
0  StateA            CityA
1  StateB            CityB
2  StateA  city of state A
3  StateB  city of state B
```